# jQuery change html in $(this) object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this jQuery code to detect click on rows in a table.

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this)
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple/v4/9a/b5/39/9ab539fb-4a39-c780-e9ec-eb58f4685141/source/512x512bb.jpg" style="width:20px; height:20px; border-radius: 10px;"></td>
  <td>Lär dig läsa</td>
  <td>2<img class="pull-right" src="/Images/arrowRight.png"></td>
</tr>
```

Now on the click i would like to change the `src` of the image in the last `<td>`, how can I do this with this `$(this)` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find('td:last img')` to get the `img` in last `td` and then change `src` using `attr` function like following.

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).find('td:last img').attr('src', 'new src');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.find()` to find the `img` and with `.attr()` change the src attribute as shown :-

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).find("img.pull-right").attr('src','new src');
});
```

OR use `:last` to find last td as shown :-

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).find('td:last img.pull-right').attr('src', 'new src');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now on the click i would like to change the src of the image in the
>   last ,

since you want to update the img source of last column on click of any column then try

```
$(this).siblings().last().find( "img" ).attr( "src" , "new URL" );
```

explantion

**Get to the last sibling**  - `$(this).siblings().last()`

**Get to the img inside last sibling** - `$(this).siblings().last().find( "img" )`

finally update the URL

Answer (score 2):

Use find on `$(this).find` with :last to get the last img and use `attr` to set the `src`

```
$(this).find( "td:last img" ).attr( "src", "new URL" ) ;
```

Comment: There are multiple `image` elements in `this`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).last().find('img').attr("src","new src")
})
```

Comment: You have missed DOT(.)  between last() and find('img').

Answer (score 1):

Use `:last` for last `td`

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $(this).find('td:last img').attr('src', 'YOUR_NEW_IMAGE_SOURCE');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) and try below code:-

```
$(this).find('td:last-child').find('img').attr('src', 'new src');
```

OR

```
$(':last-child', this).find('img').attr('src', 'new src');
```

OR

```
$(this).find(':last-child').find('img').attr('src', 'new src');
```

Hope it will help you :)